# Lonic 3 with laravel backend

Tags: laravel, ionic-framework, laravel-5, ionic3, laravel-passport

So, I am going to create an ionic 3 project that use my existing laravel backend. My laravel project is on heroku (for now) and it is already setup with laravel passport and API based in mind, since I already created frontend for laravel with SPA vuejs and already configured cors too.

So I supposed it shouldn't be any problem from my backend to communicated with client side. But I am not very experienced with ionic 3, and the problem is I can't find any one talking straight forward about how to implement basic authentication with laravel passport to ionic 3 and also the basic http request like post, get, delete, and put/patch.

Most of the tutorials are about working with firebase, and me myself is not very familiar with firebase and not willing to invest time to those since all my backend needs are already satisfied with laravel. I also found 1 or 2 site talking about laravel and ionic but i think it is from very different version of ionic since the file structure and the way he working is very different from what I've known (beside those article already 1-2 years old now)

So maybe anyone that have a tutorial about all this thing can share it to me?

Comment: Basically Ionic 3 is angular, so search how to integrate angular 2 with laravel, there are not much difference between angular 2 and 6, i learned to integrate ionic with laravel like this, and i'm able to make all kind of request and authentication between ionic and laravel, and for pple to be able to help you, please narrow down your question to more specific issue you are facing, and then once that resolved ask about other issues

Comment: I'm working on similar application, using Laravel as backend for my Ionic 3 app. I'm able consume laravel apis which is authenticated using passport.